# Proving this question

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

If first two terms of a positive AP and a positive GP are equal then prove that an AP terms can not be greater than the corresponding GP term.I assumed AP and a GP but then getting no idea ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Let the first two terms of AP be $a_1, a_1+d$ and the first two terms of GP be $a_2, a_2r$.Since the first two terms of AP are equal to the first two terms of GP, we have:
$$a_1 = a_2$$
$$a_1+d = a_2r$$
We get $d$ as :
$$d = a_2(r-1)$$

$3rd$ term of AP is : 
$$a_1+2d = a_2+2a_2(r-1)=a_2(2r-1)$$
$3rd$ term of GP is :
$$a_2r^2$$
Using $AM \geq GM$:
$$\frac{r^2+1}{2} \geq r$$
$$r^2 \geq 2r-1$$
Since the series are positive, we can conclude that $a_1,a_2$ are positive.So:
$$a_2r^2 \geq a_2(2r-1)$$

We can generalize this for $nth$ term and prove it as follows:

$nth$ term in AP is:
$$a_1+(n-1)d=a_2((n-1)r-(n-2))$$
$nth$ term in GP is:
$$a_2r^{n-1}$$
Using $AM \geq GM$:
$$\frac{r^{n-1}+(1+1+1....(n-2) times)}{n-1} \geq r$$
$$a_2r^{n-1} \geq a_2((n-1)r-(n-2))$$
Hence an AP term can never be greater than its corresponding GP term.